# Print lines with sed using line number from grep

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipe

I'm trying to pipe line numbers from grep to sed.

First I was extracting the start and end line of what I want to print with sed:

```
grep -n "Start" file1 | cut -d: -f 1 | head -n 1
grep -n "End" file1 | cut -d: -f 1 | head -n 1
```

Now I need to use these numbers to print everything from Start to End by line. E.g.

```
sed -ne '1,30w output1' file1
```

I'm not sure how this can be done as piping the line numbers to sed will be seen as "input" right?

Example:

```
Start
some text
some more text
End
Start
some text
some more text
End
```

As there's more than one start and end i cut of the rest of the line numbers from grep. And I'm supposed to combine grep and sed or is this not possible?

Comment: Why do you want `grep`, Why can't you do it with `sed` itself? `sed -n '/Start/,/End/w output1' file1`

Comment: It will help if you add an example, and how you like the output to be.

Comment: @clement Could you add it as an answer instead?

Comment: You're first numbering the line occurrences of `Start` and `End`, but right after that you strip off the numbering with `cut`. What for did you even numbered the lines?

Comment: i can't figure-out what's the actual question is.

Comment: This smells like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem, can you elaborate on the bigger picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/Start/,/End/w outputfile' -e '/End/q' file
```

This will write to `outputfile` the lines between the first `Start` and `End` and then quit and obviate the need to use grep too.

If you must use grep then perhaps:

```
sed -n "$(grep -n "Start" file | cut -d: -f 1 | head -n 1),$(grep -n "End" file | cut -d: -f 1 | head -n 1)"'p' file
```

Comment: that's exactly it. I was using the wrong syntax for the grep inside sed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without `grep`

```
sed -n '/Start/,/End/w output1' file1
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to print from the first occurrence of Start to the first subsequent occurrence of End, inclusive. That'd just be:

```
awk '/Start/{found=1} found{print; if (/End/) exit}' file
```

Comment: I like this solution better than uses the range `/Start/,/End/`, since it more flexible if you need other adaptation.

Comment: That'd be completely the wrong approach so I'm not going to but maybe someone else will help you figure that out. Good luck.